# Jekyll YAML gallery

Tags: grid, yaml, jekyll

I have a page displaying my projects in a grid layout that are being pulled from a yaml file. I can't figure out how to pull the correct data for the individual pages.

Yaml file (portfolio.yaml) is formatted like so:

```
- name: gallery one
  url: "/portfolio/gallery-one.html"
  thumbnail: /images/thumbnail.png
  decription: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit." 
- name: gallery two
  url: "/portfolio/gallery-one.html"
  thumbnail: /images/thumbnail.png
  decription: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
```

Code for the grid (works fine)

```
{% for project in site.data.portfolio %}
      {{ project.url }}
      {{ project.thumbnail }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really easy with you data file configuration.
Reorganize your file like this :

```
gallery one:
  url: "/portfolio/gallery-one.html"
  thumbnail: /images/thumbnail.png
  decription: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."

gallery two:
  url: "/portfolio/gallery-one.html"
  thumbnail: /images/thumbnail.png
  decription: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
```

You can then make a layout that will be used by all your projects pages :

**_layouts/portfolio.html**

```
---
layout: default
---
{% assign project = site.data.portfolio[page.project] %}
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ project.decription }}</p>
{{ content }}
```

Then a project page looks like this :

**gallery-one.html**

```
---
layout: portfolio
title: Gallery one
project: gallery one
---
additional content can go here
```

If you have a lot of projects you can have a look at [jekyll collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) that can auto generate pages.